# Prevent Octopus from Running a Deployment Script

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am deploying a package that contains a deploy.ps1 file. As you already know Octopus is [running this script on deploying](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+scripts#Customscripts-ScriptsinPackages) by default, I want to prevent it happening and run a custom script instead.

Comment: Why would you want to do this and are you able to rename the script file?

Comment: In my situation, the Deploy.ps1 starts all the services in my package on the deployment target. This is the default behavior same among most of targeted servers except one, where only need to start one of the services. I want to use a custom scrip instead.

Comment: Would it not be a cleaner approach  to remove the `deploy.ps1` script from that specific project and rather run the deployment powershell script in Octopus step itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a requirement like this, then it's better to move the powershell that starts the services to a separate build step and then tag the tentacles you want that script to run on.

[image: Process view]

In your deployment step for the service, set the start mode to "Manual"

[image: Service Start]

Then have a step that starts the service, and scope that script to the environments / servers that you want to auto start

[image]

The code for the step template I use here is

```
{
  "Id": "ActionTemplates-1",
  "Name": "Enable and start service",
  "Description": null,
  "ActionType": "Octopus.Script",
  "Version": 8,
  "Properties": {
    "Octopus.Action.Package.NuGetFeedId": "feeds-builtin",
    "Octopus.Action.Script.Syntax": "PowerShell",
    "Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptSource": "Inline",
    "Octopus.Action.RunOnServer": "false",
    "Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptBody": "$serviceName = $OctopusParameters[\"ServiceName\"]\n\nwrite-host \"the service is: \" $serviceName\n\n& \"sc.exe\" config $serviceName start= delayed-auto\n& \"sc.exe\" start $serviceName\n\n"
  },
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "ServiceName",
      "Label": "Service Name",
      "HelpText": null,
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$Meta": {
    "ExportedAt": "2016-10-10T10:21:21.980Z",
    "OctopusVersion": "3.3.2",
    "Type": "ActionTemplate"
  }
}
```

You may want to modify the step template as it will set the service to "Automatic - Delayed" and then start the service.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to move the script to a sub folder?

> `These scripts must be located in the root of your package`

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+scripts

Alternatively - don't include your `deploy.ps1` script in the deployment package if it should never be deployed.

[image]